# Grafo usando o python-igraph com atributos por nó e arestas

Tags: python-3.x, grafo

Fala pessoal! 
Estou tentando criar um grafo utilizando a biblioteca do Python-Igraph. Cada nó teria um atributo, por exemplo, em um grafo de livros cujo os nós seriam livros e os atributos desses nós seriam:

```
titulo: nome_do_titulo
sinopse: descricao_do_livro
autor: nome_do_autor
prefacio: descricao_do_prefacio
```

e todos esses atributos dos nós teriam arestas ligando a atributos semelhantes de outros nós contendo o peso da semelhança entre esses atributos. Assim cada nó teriam 4 arestas para outro nó.
Estou usando o python 3 e o igraph.

A maneira que estou implementando é a seguinte:

```
    g = Graph()
    g.vs["titulo"] = ['titulo1', 'titulo2', 'titulo3']
    g.vs["sinopse"] = ["sinopse1", "sinopse2", "sinopse3"]
    g.vs["autor"] = ["autor1","autor2","autor3"]
    g.vs["prefacio"] = ["prefacio1","prefacio2", "prefacio3"]
```

Agora como colocar o link ente eles sei que se utiliza `g.es` mas o site do Igraph esta um tanto quanto vago quanto a isso.

Answer (score 1):

Não conhecia esse igraph  - pelo visto é *a* biblioteca para se trabalhar com grafos em Python.

Então, dando uma olhada na documentação e experimentando no prompt interativo do Python (Esse é o segredo para descobrir como fazer as coisas) - entendi o seguinte:

A biblioteca não dá suporte de "1ª classe" para arestas vinculadas a atributos específicos dos nós - (ou talvez, o suporte que ela tenha seja considerado primeira classe - não sei :-)  )

Mas, como as arestas podem ter atributos arbitrários, você pode colocar um atributo "tipo" em cada aresta - desta forma você vai saber a qual atributo ela diz respeito. E, sendo completa, ela suporta perfeitamente mais de uma aresta conectando o mesmo par de nós, então você pode ter 2 arestas relacionando dois nós que você queira vincular tanto por título quanto por autor.

A única forma de criar uma aresta é passar os índices numéricos dos nós que ela está conectando -  eu sugiro que você coloque um atributo "tipo" (ou "type" - sempre é melhor ter todo o seu programa - variáveis inclusive em inglês - você nunca sabe quando o projeto vai crescer para ter colaboradores internacionais. Mas mais importante que ser em inglês é serem todas as variáveis e funções na mesma língua - se começou com português, continue com tudo em português) - 
Mas então, para conectar os nós "0" e "1" pelo atributo título, chame

```
g.add_edge(source=0, target=1, tipo="titulo")
```

Para achar os índices dos nós que deseja conectar mutuamente, se quiser um match exato (==) de parâmetros, pode usar a busca com "find" no objeto "g.vs"  - para outras buscas, pode usar o filtro com "if" do Python normal - e aí usar o `itertools.combinations` para ter todos os pares de arestas possíveis.

Exemplo: vamos supor que você queira conectar todos os nós cujos titulos contenham a palavra "nárnia" - pode usar uma função desse tipo:

```
import itertools 

def conecta(grafo, palavra, atributo):
   nos_relevantes = [no.index for no in grafo.vs if palavra in getattr(no, atributo, "").lower()]
   for origem, destino in itertools.product(nos_relevantes, 2):
       grafo.add_edge(source=origem, target=destino, tipo=atributo)
```

Acho que até aqui está respondida a sua pergunta. (teste no prompt interativo essas expressões, entenda como funciona o itertools.product, por exemplo, etc...)

Agora, não vi o suficiente do igraf para saber se você vai cosneguir fazer o que você quer com as arestas se distinguindo apenas por esse atributo "tipo" - agora algo que com certeza dá para fazer é, quando for precisar usar arestas específicas, criar cópias do grafo, e filtrar para o novo grafo apenas as arestas que sejam relevantes:

```
from copy imoport deep_copy
g_titulo = deepcopy(g)
g_titulo.delete_edges([e.index for  in g_titulo.es if e["tipo"] != "titulo"])
```

Em tempo: essa API do igraph para associar os parâmetros aos nós a partir de uma lista é meio maluca - não sei se é o jeito que você vai preferir usar -  eu ficaria mais confortável criando cada nó de uma vez, passando todos os parâmetros vinculados  - é como costumamos trabalhar em Python. O igraph tem suporte a isso. Ou seja, em vez de criar os vértices como está fazendo, pode fazer:

```
g = igraph.Graph()
dados = [{"titulo": "titulo1", "sinopse": "sinopse1", "autor": "autor1"}, {"titulo": "titulo2", "sinopse": "sinopse2", "autor": "autor2"}, ]
for dado in dados:
    g.add_vertex(**dado)
```

Dessa forma fica fácil colocar seus dados iniciais numa planilha,  salvar como CSV, er com o `csv.DictReader` do Python para criar um nó para cada um de seus livros, por exemplo - e você não tem que se preocupar - em paralelo ao grafo - em manter listas com cada atributo na mesma ordem em que estão os vértices.

Comment: Cada livro no caso pode ter atributos diferentes né? Tipo alguns podem faltar a Sinopse por exemplo?

Comment: POdem - mas o igraph cria os atributos para todos os livros - eles ficam "em branco" se não forem associados explicitamente. (Acho que são lidos como "None"). O fato é que se você tiver um grafo com 100 livros, e criar um atributo para um único deles, os atributo vai aparecer nos outros 99.

Comment: Tem  que usar o `**` para parametrizar o grafo ?  pode usar sem o `**` ?

Comment: A API do igraph espera que cada parametro venha como um named parameter na chamada - o "**" é a forma do Python transformar um dicionário em uma série de named parameters em tempo de execução.  Se você estiver usando parâemtros fixos, claro que pode fazer sem o **. Isso é `g.add_vertex(autor=dado["autor"], titulo=dado["titulo"], ...)` em vez  de `g.add_vertex(**dado)`  - pro outro lado se "dado" tiver sempre as mesmas chaves, o único motivo para não fazer isso é legibilidade.